# How to Hash an Entire Redshift Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-redshift, checksum

I want to hash entire redshift tables in order to check for consistency after upgrades, backups, and other modifications which shouldn't affect table data.

I've found [Hashing Tables to Ensure Consistency in Postgres, Redshift and MySQL](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/hashing-tables-to-ensure-consistency-in-postgres-redshift-and-mysql) but the solution still requires spelling out each column name and type so it can't be applied new tables in a generic manner.  I'd have to manually change column names and types.

Is there some other function or method by which I could hash / checksum entire tables in order to confirm they are identical?  Ideally without spelling out the specific column and column types of that table.

Comment: If you have the option of another DB like Snowflake which supports hash on table https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/hash.html , unload your table to s3 and load into snowflake and run the hash.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly no in-built capability in Redshift to hash whole tables.

Also, I'd be a little careful of the method suggested in that article because, from what I can see, it is calculating a hash of all the values in a column but isn't associating the hashed value with a row identifier. Therefore if Row 1 and Row 2 swapped values in a column, the hash wouldn't change. So, it's not strictly calculating an adequate hash (but I could be wrong!).

You could investigate using the new [Stored Procedures in Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) to see whether you can create a generic function that would work for any table.